# cant get ColumnIndex from db

Tags: android, database

I just cant get the index of column of my db, while others column index work ok.
the column is image (item4) and the index that i get -1

```
CursorDb.moveToFirst();
            if (CursorDb.getCount()>0)
                do
                { 
                    int i=CursorDb.getColumnIndex(item2);//ok
                    int t=CursorDb.getColumnIndex(item3);//ok
                    int z=CursorDb.getColumnIndex(item4);//not ok
                    byte b[]=CursorDb.getBlob(4);
```

where my create code and insert work correctly. 
the create is

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists  titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "link text not null UNIQUE, RssTitle text not null,Rtl text not null,image BLOB);";
```

thanks for help!

Comment: What is the value of `item4`?

Comment: the item4 is string that value is image

Comment: Did you pass the correct columns into SQLiteDatabase.query(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getColumnIndex()` returns -1 that means the column is not in your query. Double check your SELECT statement and add `item4`.

```
"SELECT " + item2 + ", " + item3 + ", " + item4 + ", FROM " + TABLE_NAME....
```

Also `Cursor#moveToFirst()` returns true or false, depending on whether the Cursor is empty or not. You don't need to use both `moveToFirst()` and `getCount()`:

```
if(CursorDb.moveToFirst())
    do 
    {
```